# Romans 10:17 - the absence of article means salvation comes by rhema of Christ not logos?

Tags: greek, romans

I would like to know the importance of the absence of an article in greek NT. In Romans 10:17 I see a commentary of a preacher saying that to understand salvific faith we need to see interpretation of Rhema in this 10:17. Argument says because there is not article in greek - cannot be referring to written word - logos - Bible - hear the written word. So, absence of article means doesn't need to speak - refer to the Bible - written.So that means that as it is rhema - the chosen word by Paul - is not referring to the written of God. So salvific faith is by Rhema not by written word. so the conclusion is that saving faith is by rhema. And of course this rhema has to be compare - contrasted with the written word of God. any thoughts? thanks in advance!

Comment: For the importance and place of the article in Koine Greek, I suggest you consult "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics" by Wallace - it has several chapters devoted to the subject.  An answer here can never condense that much material into less than 5000 words,

Answer (score 0):

The theme here is in Ro 10.14:

> Πῶς οὖν ἐπικαλέσωνται εἰς ὃν οὐκ ἐπίστευσαν; πῶς δὲ πιστεύσωσιν οὗ οὐκ ἤκουσαν; πῶς δὲ ἀκούσωσιν χωρὶς κηρύσσοντος;

> How can people call upon the one who they do not believe? How can they believe the one they have not heard? How can they hear without someone preaching?

The path is, reversing the order, hearing the message, having faith in it and calling upon it.

The verse you ask about, verse 17, sums up verse 14:

> ἄρα ἡ πίστις ἐξ ἀκοῆς, ἡ δὲ ἀκοὴ διὰ ῥήματος Χριστοῦ.

> Faith then comes from what is heard and what is heard comes from the word of Christ. (could also be the object genitive: the word about Christ, I suppose).

From your question

> Argument says because there is not article in greek - cannot be referring to written word - logos - Bible - hear the written word.

See

> BDF §260(2) p. 136: Χριστός is properly an appellative = the Messiah, which comes to expression in the Gospels and Acts in the frequent appearance of the article; the Epistles usually (but not always) omit the article.

The “article” you are looking for here is usually omitted in the epistles. The the “word”, ῥήματος, is definite anyway, “Christ’s word”, “the word of Christ”.

I am not sure one could draw conclusions about this contra the written word, but it is the spoken word referred to here.

Please keep in mind that the vast majority were illiterate. Some say that only about 10% of the population could read and the first Christians did not come (exclusively) from the upper ranks of society. So for most of them, even if the "written word" was an issue, they would be "hearing" it as someone else read aloud.

It is not necessary to revert to subtle grammatical niceties to interpret this passage as referring to the spoken preaching rather than reading.